# Is there any difference between `git branch -Dr ...` vs. deleting the file directly in refs/remotes/origin?

Tags: git

Is there any real difference between deleting a remote branch with

```
git branch -Dr origin/<branch name>
```

vs. deleting

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/<branch name>
```

directly?

As far as I can tell, there isn't, but it's preferred to do any git operations with the intended git CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes:**

If the branch has been added to `.git/packed-refs`, deleting the unpacked ref file (if it exists—it will if the remote-tracking branch has been updated since said packing) will simply restore the packed ref, but deleting the branch with the front end command will delete both copies.

Also, the front end command deletes the reflog for the branch (if said reflog exists).
This is both good (prevents problems later) and bad (you can't get the reflog back if you change your mind).

Comment: Assuming that you remove it from both the `refs` folder and the `packed-refs`, and ignoring the reflog, is there still any difference left?

Comment: @poke: no, or at least, not today, but before there were packed refs, one could have said that about just removing the file and reflog, so using the documented method is more future-proof.